# Image urls won't display as Image in Metabase Table

Tags: postgresql, metabase

I saw Metabase has a cool feature since v0.31 enabling to display images inside a table view.
I've got an image_url field in my Postgres DB populated with values like 'https://pngimg.com/uploads/google/google_PNG19624.png'.

I did change the Type to 'Image URL' in Admin > Data Model, and I'm able to select 'Image' in 'View as link or image' image_url field dropdown, but in the table view, it will still appears as a link.
I tried with Metabase v0.31 and latest Metabase v0.36.6

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should change it :

- In the data model, use "no semantic data type"
- In the question, use "image"

https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/6265#issuecomment-469778261